# Oracle JDK and OpenJDK in production environment

Tags: java

Is it possible to change from Oracle JDK to OpenJDK in production environment specially for JAVA EE applications?

Comment: Yes for supported platforms, but exactly how depends on the platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically Yes. However in practice, There are many projects that work fine on Oracle JDK but not on OpenJDK and vice versa.

Since even a simple patch update of your JDK may lead to problems in your system, you have to thoroughly test the compatibility in a test environment first before moving in production.